# Ways to write n as sum of two or more positive integers

Tags: java, arrays

I found a code online about **count the ways to write n as sum of two or more positive integers**.

I cannot understand how the function is working. please can anybody explain to me

```
class sum
{
    static int countways(int n)
    {
        int table[]= new int[n+1];
        Arrays.fill(table,0);
        table[0]=1;
        for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
        {
            for(int j=i;j<=n;j++)
            {
                table[j]+=table[j-i];
            }
        }
        return table[n];
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        countways[n];


    }
}
```

Comment: First you run this code this.. put some print statements in between and try to understand the logic. If you have any specific question please come back

Comment: Run it with a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

It calculates count the ways to write n as sum of two or more positive integers **for all integers from 1 to n**.

The idea is:

n = n0 + n1 + ... + nx = n0 + (n - n0)

We iterate over the possible values of n0 and look at the table we built up until that point for how many ways there are to express (n - n0).

This is a good example of the more general idea of [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). The general idea is if we have a recursive problem, where a lot of sub-problems are the same, we can save time by saving the results of the subproblems and reusing them.

Comment: I can't understand where the counting is happening.?  no count variable is initialized

Comment: @josewatson table[i] => the counts for i

Comment: Any way the answers can be printed out?

Comment: @Wildhammer System.out.println  ?? Or what do you mean?

Comment: No what I meant was to actually have those counted answers. So if there are 5 possible ways for example, what are those 5 ways?

Comment: @Wildhammer Instead of an integer array `table`, use an Array of List of List of Integer (n -> LIst of Lists of integers that sum to n), everything else more or less stays the same.

Comment: I found this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/perfect-sum-problem-print-subsets-given-sum/ but I'm not sure what the time complexity is